# Why is this class using "self" as a positional argument?

Tags: python

I wrote the following code to add a Listing to the `Marketplace` class, but it throws an error saying that `.add_listing(`) is missing one positional argument, while `add_listing` takes `self` and `new_listing` as arguments. I tried removing `self` to see what happened, and it threw another error.

Take a look:

```
class Marketplace:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listings = []
    def add_listing(self, new_listing):
        self.listings.append(new_listing)
    def remove_listing(self, listing):
        self.listings.remove(listing)
    def show_listings(self):
        for listing in self.listings:
            print(listing)

class Client:
    def __init__(self, name, location, is_museum):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.is_museum = is_museum
    def sell_artwork(self, artwork, price):
        if artwork.owner == self:
            listed_artwork = Listing(artwork, price, self)
            veneer.add_listing(listed_artwork)

class Listing:
    def __init__(self, art, price, seller):
        self.art = art
        self.price = price
        self.seller = seller
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.art.title, str(self.price))
```

When `.sell_artwork` is called on a `Client`, it throws this error:
(`veneer` is an instance of `Marketplace` that I am using in this code)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 45, in <module>
  edytta.sell_artwork(girl_with_mandolin, '$6M (USD)')   
    File "script.py", line 30, in sell_artwork
      veneer.add_listing(listed_artwork) 
        TypeError: add_listing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_listing'
```

Comment: Did you write `veneer = Marketplace` instead of `veneer = Marketplace()`?

Comment: (Also, `veneer` should probably be an argument to the method, rather than a global variable that the `Client` class depends on.)

Comment: @chepner thank you, I had called Marketplace without the brackets, and this solved the problem!